# SKSpriteNodes in SKView

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skview

I am trying to get all the SKSpriteNodes in my SKView to change their alpha. Here's my code:

```
if let nodes = self.gameSKView.scene!.children as? [SKSpriteNode] {
        for node in nodes {
            if node.name != "bg" {
                node.alpha = 0
            }
        }
}
```

With those codes, the nodes is always nil but when I print what in my gameSKView it is not nil.

```
println("\(self.gameSKView.scene!.children)")
```

Can anyone try to help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use sprite kits node enumeration, see sk programming guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.gameSKView.scene!.children as? [SKSpriteNode]
```

is non-null if *all* the children are `SKSpriteNode` - `as?` is not a filter to select elements of a particular type, it's a type-safe "cast".

I's very difficult to provide any advice how to do what you want without knowing what you want to accomplish and more of the code.

Comment: I casted it with "as? [SKSpriteNode]" because I know that all the children in my gameSKView is SKSpriteNode. I want to change the alpha of each node in my gameSKView. Now i want is the proper way because apparently, nodes variable is null